# How to ensure that only one item is added to janusgraph

Tags: scala, janusgraph

Is there a way that I can ensure that any creation of a vertex in janusgraph with a given set of properties only results in one such vertex being created?

Right now, what I do is I traverse the graph and ensure that the number of vertices I find with particular properties is only one. For example:

```
val g = graph.traversal
val vertices = g.V().has("type", givenType).has("name", givenName).toList
if (vertices.size > 1) { 
  // the vertex is not unique, cannot add vertex
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with the so called *get or create* traversal which is described in [TinkerPop's Element Existence recipe](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.3.4/recipes/#element-existence) and in the section [Using coalesce to only add a vertex if it does not exist](http://kelvinlawrence.net/book/Gremlin-Graph-Guide.html#coaladdv) of the Practical Gremlin book.

For your example, this traversal would look like this:

```
g.V().has("type", givenType).has("name", givenName).
  fold().
  coalesce(unfold(),
           addV("yourVertexLabel").
              property("type", givenType).
              property("name", givenName))
```

Note however, that it depends on the graph provider whether this is an atomic operation or not. In your case of JanusGraph, the existence check and the conditional vertex addition are executed with two different operations which can lead to a race condition when two threads execute this traversal at the same time in which case you can still end up with two vertices with these properties. So, you currently need to ensure that two threads can't execute this traversal for the same properties in parallel, e.g., with locks in your application.

I just published a blog post about exactly this topic: [How to Avoid Doppelgängers in a Graph Database](https://www.gdatasoftware.com/blog/2018/12/31280-how-to-avoid-doppelgangers-in-a-graph-database) if you want to get more information about this topic in general. It also describes distributed locking as a way to implement locks for distributed systems and discusses possible improvements to better support upserts in JanusGraph in the future.